# Android: File download of 100+ KB becomes 1 KB

Tags: java, android, xml, download

I'm was able to parse an xml file and I want to download the files given its url by the xml. I have the following codes:

```
    try{
        /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
        URL url = new URL("http://dev2.eacomm.com/tabletcms/tablets/sync_login/jayem30/jayem");
        url.openConnection();
        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
        ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        /* Parsing has finished. */

        /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
        List<ParsedExampleDataSet> parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

        Iterator i;
        i = parsedExampleDataSet.iterator();
        ParsedExampleDataSet dataItem;

        while(i.hasNext()){
                dataItem = (ParsedExampleDataSet) i.next();
                String folder = dataItem.getParentTag();

                if( folder == "Videos"  ){

                    String [] videoName = dataItem.getName().split("/");
                    String currentFile = videoName[0] + "." + videoName[1];
                    String currentFileURL = dataItem.getUrl() + videoName[0] + "." + videoName[1];
                    tv.append("\nURL: " + currentFileURL);


                    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(currentFile , currentFileURL, "Videos");
                    this.videoCount++;
                    tv.append("\nVideo Count: " + this.videoCount );
                }

                if( folder == "Slideshows" ){
                    //processSlideshows(dataItem, folder);   
                }      
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The download code is on the async task. However, when I run this, the two files I'm supposedly downloaded (126kb and 98kb) is downloaded, the files are there but their sizes are both 1kb only. the file doesn't play.

when I change the line

```
**new DownloadFileAsync().execute(currentFile , currentFileURL, "Videos");** 
to 
**new DownloadFileAsync().execute("hehe.flv", "http://dev2.eacomm.com/tabletcms/app/webroot/files/000002/videos/27.flv", "Videos");**
```

the file size is fine but it returns only one file.

**EDIT:**

```
//---------------------------- START DownloadFileAsync -----------------------//
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            String currentFile = strings[0];
            String currentFileURL = strings[1];
            String folder = strings[2];

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            URL u = new URL(currentFileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(root + "/Engagia/Downloads/" + folder, currentFile));

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            long total = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                total += len1; //total = total + len1
                publishProgress("" + (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Downloader", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

}
//---------------------------- END DownloadFileAsync -----------------------//

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading files...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```

EDIT: (thanks to Haphazard)

My bad, I rechecked my URL and I found out that my XML stream does not return the correct url for download so I had to reconstruct a URL for download. I did something like:

```
tv.append("\nCurrent File URL: " + currentFileURL);
String downloadFileURL = currentFileURL.replace( "tablets/tablet_content", "app/webroot/files" );
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `currentFile` and `currentFileURL` are both correct?  Try debugging through the code to see if they are formed properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, yes they are both correct, I tried other urls actually

Comment: Do you get any errors from your downloader?  `Log.d("Downloader", e.getMessage());` output would be very interesting to see.  Also that should be `Log.e` for "error".  `Log.d` is for "debug" statements.

Comment: Hi @Haphazard, my bad, you are right, my urls are not formed correctly, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Great.  I added an answer so you can close this question off properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your URLs are formed properly.  Have you confirmed that `currentFile` and `currentFileURL` are both correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code which is in async task. I feel the issue is in downloading the file from the url.

See the following url to get how to download a file.

[ANDROID: How do I download a video file to SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692252/android-how-do-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Hi thanks for your response @Deepak, I updated the question, now with download code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
package com.endeavour.sampleprograms;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private static final String DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
//        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            String currentFile = strings[0];
            String currentFileURL = strings[1];
            String folder = strings[2];
*emphasized text*
            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Engagia/Downloads/" + folder+"/";
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(fileName);
            if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
                wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            fileName = fileName+currentFile;
            downloadFromUrl(currentFileURL, fileName);
            //            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(root + "/Engagia/Downloads/" + folder, currentFile));

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }


    public void downloadFromUrl(String VideoURL, String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
        try {
            System.out.println("....Url....."+VideoURL);
                URL url = new URL(VideoURL); //you can write here any link
                File file = new File(fileName);

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                              /* Open a connection to that URL. */
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                /*
                 * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                 */
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                /*
                 * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                 */
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

Thanks Deepak