# Video viewing in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

Dos android Video-View support catching video from url , i mean when video get played once i dont want the Video-view to re-download it.
And if not whats the best alternative for a Video-view smooth scrolling is required  ?

Comment: Seems like you need to review the various video deliver formats (different than video encoding formats). Also are you aware of Exoplayer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: i cant find anything about caching in Exoplayer

Comment: See: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/57 and https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/420

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android-How to enable cache or buffering when videoView have downloaded a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184497/android-how-to-enable-cache-or-buffering-when-videoview-have-downloaded-a-video)

Comment: @HannesLandeholm will it Possible is there is no answer there also