# How to play a remote video after downloading it to local storage in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to play a video which is hosted in web after downloading it to the local storage of the phone. Currently I have tried to stream a video online. But what I wanted is first the video should be automatically downloaded to user's storage and able to play it through the app (Video playing url should be local storage).

What I tried

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.MediaController;

import android.widget.VideoView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

    String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    vidView.start();

}
```

Comment: you can simply pass local video path to MediaController  here is example http://www.javatpoint.com/playing-video-in-android-example

Comment: Thank you very much @Pavan , But for task , I have to use url and should download it first. After that I can use this method.

Comment: if you want to download it and play or online streaming

Comment: @Pavan- download it and play.

Comment: so first write download file in local storage  and after  successful download pass the local url to player http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816995/how-can-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card

Comment: Thank you very much @Pavan. This helps me a lot.

Comment: Great to know it helped you