# Trouble downloading video file greater than 3.5mb

Tags: java, android, video

I'm able to successfully send, the encoded video byte[](in string) of any size, response from server, but while downloading in mobile i always encounter MemoryOutOfBoundException when the video requested exceeds 3.5mb(approx), otherwise works fine.

The code below is the one I'm currently using.

```
String image = (encoded byte[] in form of string from server);
byte[] byteImageData = new byte[image.length()];
byteImageData = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
System.gc();

BufferedOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.write(byteImageData);
    out.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
finally {
    if (out != null) {
    out.close();
}
System.gc();
```

All I need is that the mobile should be capable enough to download atleast 20mb.
Can anyone please help me out to overcome this problem?

Comment: Try downloading using AsyncTask. Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7847019/8770539

Comment: Tried, still facing the same problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use Android's Download Manager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Then Check register for broadcast receiver to listein for file download.

Please check this example: http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

Comment: this will work for android API 9 or higher, but need solution for android API 8

Comment: For old devices I can suggest to use libcurl using NDK. Compatible from API 1.0