# How to download tiktok video without watermark Android java

Tags: java, android

How to download TikTok videos without watermark, I was using the old method but that is not working now. Now as tiktok changed there method so it is not working I even found a way to get the URL with a watermark but it gives access denied eg. URL

https://v16-web-newkey.tiktokcdn.com/5c8801735eeb489ad3c0b2af7010aec5/5f6d9749/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/2ee73819ae364f6f989c058a40763879/?a=1988&br=3656&bt=1828&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=202009250107420101151510441819C37F&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=M2h2b3A4aXc4dzMzOTczM0ApNzo3NDg7aDs5NzZlNThnZGdhc2lnZG9hNF9fLS1fMTRzczNjLmAxMjIwMmM0YDRgYl46Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=

this website works fine https://tiktok.codespikex.com/

here is the old method code:

```
  @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class Data extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {

            if (!fromService) {

                pd.dismiss();
            }
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String Line;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Log.e("Hello_myurl_is0 ", String.valueOf(reader.lines()));
            }
            while ((Line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Hello_myurl_is ", Line);
                if (Line.contains("videoData")) {


                    Line = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("videoData"));
                    Log.e("Hello_myurl_is1 ", Line);
                    Line = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("urls"));
                    Log.e("Hello_myurl_is2 ", Line);
                    VideoTitle = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("text"));
                    if (VideoTitle.contains("#")) {
                        VideoTitle = VideoTitle.substring(ordinalIndexOf(VideoTitle, "\"", 1) + 1, ordinalIndexOf(VideoTitle, "#", 0));
                    } else {
                        VideoTitle = VideoTitle.substring(ordinalIndexOf(VideoTitle, "\"", 1) + 1, ordinalIndexOf(VideoTitle, "\"", 2));
                    }
                    System.out.println("myvideo titljklfjdfd " + VideoTitle);
                    Line = Line.substring(ordinalIndexOf(Line, "\"", 1) + 1, ordinalIndexOf(Line, "\"", 2));
                    Log.e("Hello_myurl_is3 ", Line);
                    if (!Line.contains("https")) {
                        Line = Line.replace("http", "https");
                    }
                    Log.e("Hello_myurl_is4 ", Line);

                    buffer.append(Line);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!fromService) {

                pd.dismiss();
            }
            return "Invalid Video URL or Check Internet Connection";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(s)) {
            String path = createDirectory();
            if (VideoTitle == null || VideoTitle.equals("")) {
                VideoTitle = "TiktokVideo" + new Date().toString() + ".mp4";
            } else {
                VideoTitle = VideoTitle + ".mp4";
            }
            File newFile = new File(path, VideoTitle);


            new downloadFile().Downloading(context, s, VideoTitle, ".mp4");
   
        } else {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
                Looper.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think if you directly download the file from src tag of tiktok has no watermark ref :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816995/how-can-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card

Comment: sir but we don't know the location where TikTok locally saves the videos, this won't help.  this website works fine https://tiktok.codespikex.com/

Comment: are they not watermarked for a reason?

Comment: tiktok has both versions the watermarked and non-watermarked.

Comment: https://tiktok.codespikex.com/ have you checked that the downloaded video is playing? because I checked its downloading but not playing

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: no sir still waiting for an answer

Comment: @SyedUsamaAhmad hi, have you found any solution for this? same issue i am facing and i am also trying to find out, but didn't get anything. Have you got solution?

Comment: https://ttdownloader.com/ have you tried this one??

Comment: yes but i need a way to download the videos without watermark

Comment: ```https://tiktok.codespikex.com/download?id=6964751088691989761&type=video``` or ```https://tiktok.codespikex.com/download?id=6964751088691989761&type=music``` works for me

Comment: sir, i have tried this already but I get corrupted file can you tell me how you do it

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: nope still waiting

Answer (score -1):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION : DOWNLOADING TIKTOK VIDEO WITH WATERMARK**

*STEP 1: Add to build.gradle*

```
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
```

*STEP 2: Add your cookie (from Tiktok.com - try to find it using chrome dev tools), Working EXAMPLE:*

```
    "tt_webid_v2=6968990058163848705; tt_webid=6968990058163848705; MONITOR_WEB_ID=6968990058163848705; _ga=GA1.2.1315239861.1622594624; passport_csrf_token=d08d697c6bf8996de200c21ef8be7c8f; passport_csrf_token_default=d08d697c6bf8996de200c21ef8be7c8f; passport_auth_status=4461f506dcbaaf2dc0ca07dbec6da47c%2C; passport_auth_status_ss=4461f506dcbaaf2dc0ca07dbec6da47c%2C; sid_guard=9eed4fa6763dceed51cd86d0ca27202e%7C1622769381%7C5184000%7CTue%2C+03-Aug-2021+01%3A16%3A21+GMT; uid_tt=1b45d3452d8c51a951b9159bffae68918d8fce847ff46c3b762385d076ad9b0d; uid_tt_ss=1b45d3452d8c51a951b9159bffae68918d8fce847ff46c3b762385d076ad9b0d; sid_tt=9eed4fa6763dceed51cd86d0ca27202e; sessionid=9eed4fa6763dceed51cd86d0ca27202e; sessionid_ss=9eed4fa6763dceed51cd86d0ca27202e; store-idc=alisg; store-country-code=cn; odin_tt=f9dfc6847fc4deb428d6560a0eee1ac6da7621e81e4bc66e48ca11d9b94e944ed465bc13dddaeecffe52066ab1f3c54de75bdb9d835ffab67ce46f6f38ec77f6209383977e1a0909c2043fabd8b45ff4; tt_csrf_token=dgOsuRkyci3vAyVbQrti_Ocf; csrf_session_id=a547a648622c44b9bca4ca0511e7540e; s_v_web_id=verify_kpiysnzz_xjFVty6E_o1pv_44hq_B1sf_4WKo9WU4hKnH; xgplayer_device_id=40509682259; xgplayer_user_id=703950030384; bm_sz=CBFF5398784179C9F43AAB6CBA6C039F~YAAQLHTCF/xyJst5AQAAC5P25AzUNANKT9ugqun9O+rFsGco3TICngDvsZZC2mV1sEGkchzYF38i9vYgaTSlxK41SIR17mjIQkw/fnhyeWJBMube6GkI8fv/BD7SzDOvtEXOerSCk8UwzBSaE2kxFC/K2j+Q/On9kOt1CGlkU2H7k0uzQMToSgvLNWEY0qTd; _abck=FAAE0713AB570A9C7357AC429302A0E8~-1~YAAQLHTCF/1yJst5AQAAC5P25AbsU8gINg7Sz+k5U1NJZK21u2/SfwcAiV1Z3rIbusd/Yn0Hao4t3rwmfr0cy/vQFoTPhb1/SJFjwbV2l5SESSp66mrYxnyseQF88EZyKLo0ZdLX+2a/X96ee0H3WVjTnc5bGUPaaTMIbj13s//1Na4GrbuOhjlDZzR3dGHILVw7uX6ies55m74WERBFLYLSPoEsBBl/1hT9Uq9MKpHCYDWkw54/vQ3N+Us9SglLZu5hXmZUlkl1hKCZ36CpyQrV8+vAnxMgNn3d6cjDqWK3vleTBb5vfx5DL602ByWHxOGAxjSdvLiU2f+Len+/iBILH/LEigNrW3xVPUldIjRG8Q/XqBZ+yMYMYPMBIRT2ssYaFG42YBjnlw==~-1~-1~-1; cmpl_token=AgQQAPPdF-RMpYxYfIog4Jk8-tdKu3OK_4PZYP9bfw; ttwid=1%7C_2DQhAb3FNdJO7TeEViwfBMb6tdOOpeS_jCEDDvWbQo%7C1623053481%7Cf9eca73a998726391f6ea768029a455df15d98514f9e2db9eaf76923815f1147; R6kq3TV7=AJW9huV5AQAAaPD3BP-74Sa5ENc8YjPGPmaoV6zprTPuHXNU0e8XxFEXLH7t|1|0|8b7c8d63a889aa2f48e4084853b1f4c3a58ad403; ak_bmsc=8878D47FB0062375E549B53BDBDC797617C2743D3E3B0000ADD4BD60ACBAC402~plxj3R+QWYAe5cIlRvJ6392wOlUtm3KxMZu769G1krI5pnVrzNig4P9mCPsOFc3hXyoagE5JOhfPSkkkjq/J+EjvZ2cSNwCovppDU4S7Klg4jSh+RwxUGMa7k48ab1HLSLcH2P3bSJpWyGQazN/Pen6+MtIS43hIndhCw9zTEELoJ0gEHoxlswYXfc1wGiyNOL2vR3YvQ+nEHuK2aXkwJzSriVYnH9yh8opa+39xVz7BQ=; bm_sv=16A7BCAC64C5999ECEFB83EAABF366C3~6vMhfeLgJoeI/bgNVuRnUopkAuGnrODmT0AvCYqnyXm1gcM0mckyo4UX1NRqb6yfoVgV0vqXbOs/kd3riX9Vv7zT1/2NxE5M2vZPq+1dKt9rULjESkhYSL558gY0AkstIaiPRAQSBQ+O5yonWRJ1Tbe2MH3fmgcfsp3VCiPAKYM="
```

*STEP 3: Add to your activity/downloading class*

```
    private Map<String, String> buildCookiesMap(String cookieStr) {
    Map<String, String> cookieMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] cookieArr = cookieStr.split("; ");
    Arrays.stream(cookieArr).forEach(cookie -> {
        String[] split = cookie.split("=");
        cookieMap.put(split[0], split[1]);
    });
    return cookieMap;
}
```

*STEP 4: Add to your downloading method(change **file** to your File object)*

```
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36")
                    .cookies(buildCookiesMap(cookie))
                    .referrer("https://m.tiktok.com/")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .execute()
                    .bodyAsBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("TiktokDownloader", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Log.w("TiktokDownloader", "Done Downloading process.");
        }
```

Comment: hello sir thanks for the answer but I can download the video with a watermark but do you know  of any way to get the video id from the video to get it without watermark eg. https://api-h2.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v07044230000bto6s4p5pij8848sae90&line=0&is_play_url=1&source=PackSourceEnum_AWEME_DETAIL&file_id=5f0801210f564925b1f10079221c468a       
                                                                      
                video_id=v07044230000bto6s4p5pij8848sae90

Comment: this website can do https://youtube4kdownloader.com/ajax/getLinks.php?video=https%3A%2F%2Fvm.tiktok.com%2FZSQTnNWu%2F&rand=7a6d56d6659b6