# How to download video file from url to sd card

Tags: android, video, download, sd-card

I am trying to download a video file from url in folder in sd card of real device not on emulator.Code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoDownload extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    File folder =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyFolder");
    folder.mkdir();
    try{ 

    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Myfolder";
URL url = new URL("my url/song.mp4");
File file = new File(fileName);
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
baf.append((byte) current);
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }

    }
    }
```

I am getting no any error but video file didn't download in folder. What am i doing wrong?
Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not doing anything in the catch block. There's no way to know anything about the error or if there is one. Log the exception and you'll probably get something useful.

Comment: I have write Log.d("ERROR.......",e+""); in exception but no error message displayed in logcat.

Comment: I have found error i.e java.net.unknownhostexception:www.myurl.com. How can i solve that now?

Comment: This post should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692252/android-how-do-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
                    try
                    {
                        URL u = new URL(URLS.host_url_main + ce.getString(4));
                        URLConnection ucon = u.openConnection();
                        //Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                        // uses 3KB download buffer
                        File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ptlinkx/"+ce.getString(4).replace("/ExerciseVideo/2/", ""));
                        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
                        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

                        //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
                        int len;
                        while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1)
                        {
                            outStream.write(buff,0,len);
                        }

                        //clean up
                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();
                        inStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception se)
                    {
                         se.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Add INTERNET uses permission in manifest file

Comment: The poster states that there is no error. If the INTERNET permission were missing and required, the application would be terminated with an error in the log that stated the lack of permission and the stack dump at the time of failure.