# Download Video on SDCard from url

Tags: android, video, rss, download, video-streaming

I am having an application to download video on sdcard from url. I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692252/android-how-do-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card/3692492#3692492). But this link contains the url as .mp4 format. I have to download news feed videos. My format is not .mp4 format. It will be mostly .swf.
 The url of mine is,

`http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/wid/_483511/uiconf_id/5590821/entry_id/0_cf39ej0c`

I was getting this url by parsing rss feed( news feed).

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final String PATH = "/sdcard/downloadVideo/";
    private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 5000;// 5sec
    private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 300000;// 30sec
    //public final String imageURL = "http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50149183n&tag=api";
    public final String imageURL = "http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/wid/_483511/uiconf_id/5590821/entry_id/0_cf39ej0c";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DownloadFromUrl(imageURL, PATH);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void DownloadFromUrl(String VideoURL, String fileName) { // this is
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // downloader
                                                                    // method
        try {
            URL url = new URL(VideoURL);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i(TAG, "image download beginning: " + VideoURL);

            // Open a connection to that URL.
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            // this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize
            // there's a connection problem
            ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

            // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            // uses 3KB download buffer
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

            // Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to
            // read(-1)
            int len;
            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }

            // clean up
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "download completed in "
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                    + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("VideoManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

But I couldn't get this video?

Actually I am trying to achieve video streaming. But I don't know that how to do it.

Am i doing any wrong in my code?

Please give your suggestion to achieve the above.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the file get downloaded in the path you given.. I feel your PATH value is wrong.. U need to give the path as **"/mnt/sdcard/filename"** .. **Ur path is not pointing to a file instead its pointing to a folder**.. check that too

Comment: now I am getting output as " download completed in 3 sec". In /mnt/, that path also created. But, While i am checking in gallery, i couldn't find out that video alone.

Comment: U could see the video in that path? i.e., if u have given the filename as abc.mp4, is t present in the path /mnt/sdcard/abc.mp4

Comment: It is not a .mp4 format na? We are only giving as a .mp4 format? will it be present?

Comment: It is present in the path already. But i couldn't find out in gallery

Comment: If u r trying to do video streaming y u r downloading the video. U should use "videoview" . If u click on that downloaded file what is happening?

Comment: I am downloading video for later use. First time, the video have to play while downloading, once it is downloaded on sdcard, it will play from sdcard. Nothing will happen, when click on that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of defining the path to the SD card manually, use

```
String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

and add a file name behind that, like

```
String filename = Path + "/filename.mp4"
```

and pass these `filename` strings to your `FileOutputStream`s.

**Edit:**

Instead of downloading the file, view it directly using VideoView, with code like this:

```
VideoView mVideoView;
MediaController mcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    String videourl="http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/wid/_483511/uiconf_id/5590821/entry_id/0_cf39ej0c";
    mcon.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView); // add this line
    mcon = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mcon);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videourl));
    mcon.show();
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

And dont forget to mention the internet permission in `androidmanifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: It is not a .mp4 format na? We are only giving as a .mp4 format? will it be present?

Comment: buddy you should use the same extension of the file which is being specified in the source file.. like if i want to download detail.txt then i should specify my destination file as filename.txt..

Comment: It is present in the path already. But i couldn't find out in gallery.After doing this also, remaining same

Comment: Thats also my problem, it is .swf format mostly. BUt Android doesn't support it na. Thats y, I have mentioned my url in my question.

Comment: For downloading file from a url we always need extension of it.. and in your case use are using Url which is used for viewing video only.. you cant even download it directly in your PC browser also..

Comment: Then how can i display this in my app?

Comment: Use a videoview and pass these url in it.. But everytime you view the video it will use your internet..

Comment: I am downloading video for later use. First time, the video have to play while downloading, once it is downloaded on sdcard, it will play from sdcard. I Couldn't achieve this?

Comment: I am getting "Cannot play video" dialogue box only, When using the above code

Comment: I have added, no change...:(