# Convert byte array to video in android

Tags: android, url, video-streaming

I have a Url and I have to download video from that url. My application is designed in such a way that I can access the video data as byte array only. I am getting the videoframes but only the last frame is get recorded.My code is given below.Anyone please help.

```
frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
        skipBytes(headerLen);
        readFully(frameData);
        System.out.println("frameData "+frameData);


        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/req_videos");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        file = new File(myDir, "Sample.mp4");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(frameData);
        //out.write(frameData, 0, frameData.length);
        out.close();
```

Comment: do u need to download to sdcard or directly have to stream on video player

Comment: I have to download it in sdcard

Comment: try this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692252/android-how-do-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can **convert your byte array into an InputStream**, like this:

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray);
```

Then you can loop through it and get your output file.

```
InputStream input = ...;
OutputStream output = output = new FileOutputStream("yourfilename");
byte data[] = new byte[4096];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: I dont have inputstream with me. I need to convert byte array to video

Comment: You can convert your ByteArray to an Inputstream sir, look at the first line

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful you can accept it. It's really appreciated.

Comment: Same issue? Explain me and I can help you

Comment: I think the video frames are overwriting. I can view only the last frame as a video.

Comment: How do you download the video? If you are downloadeding from a real time video source, be aware that you should keep a connection open to download frames continuously