# Can i loop multiple videos stored on raw folder in videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview

What im trying to achieve is to play multiple videos stored on raw folder to be played on loop and sequentially one after the other?

I can play only one in loop in videoview but cant access other ones.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my videoview.

```
private VideoView myVideo1;
String path = "http://192.168.0.22/output/files/video/";
Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myVideo1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    myVideo1.setVideoURI(uri);
    myVideo1.start();
    myVideo1.requestFocus();

    myVideo1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please define "I cant access other ones". Have you tried calling `.setVideoURI(uri)` on you `VideoView`?

Comment: Yes, look my code above.

Comment: you are never updating your `path` and also it doesn't point to any asset. Is your question actually *how can I access and play videos located in the `raw` directory*?

Comment: What im trying to achieve is to play videos located in raw folder as a playlist in loop one after another

Comment: check my answer. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play multiple videos located in `raw`, try the following approach:

(**NOTE**: take care of the index and your video files naming. This example assumes your videos are named *video1*, *video2*..... *videoX*)

```
private final int COUNT = 3;
private int index = 1;
private VideoView myVideo1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myVideo1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    myVideo1.requestFocus();
    myVideo1.setVideoURI(getPath(index));
    index++;

    myVideo1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            myVideo1.start();
        }
    });

    myVideo1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                //videos count +1 since we started with 1
            if (index == COUNT + 1) index = 1;
            myVideo1.setVideoURI(getPath(index));
            index++;
        }
    });
}

private Uri getPath(int id) {
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/video" + id);
}
```

Getting resources from `raw` explained:  `android.resource://` is a constant part of the path, `getPackageName()` points to your application, `/raw/` tells the system where to look for the file, `video` is *the constant naming prefix of your files* and the id *is a dynamic suffix* of your file names.

`VideoView` uses the `MediaPlayer` for playing videos, here's an overview of its states (taken from the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)) for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but just tried and is not working. Switched  myVideo1.prepare(); with mediaplayer.prepare(); cause it gave me an error and still nothing

Comment: @Aldo oh I see, the answer contained some mistakes since I wasn't able to test it at the moment of answering. Please check the updated code, it works on my Nexus 5

Comment: It finally works, thanks a lot :) 
One other question how to download videos to raw folder and that play it in videoview on loop. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Aldo no, you can't download files into `raw`, `assets` etc. since those directories are read-only at runtime. To do so, you'd need to download your videos to device's storage and then use a similar approach and the one I have shown.

Comment: Do you have any near example for that? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Aldo, there're tons of examples on SO. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816995/how-can-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692252/android-how-do-i-download-a-video-file-to-sd-card) and a lot more. Using such an approach you'll have the file path so you won't really need my `getPath()` method