# Play all videos from local directory in a loop

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, local-files

I am trying play all videos from local directory in a loop.But only first video is playing in a loop ,net view is not playing .

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getInit();
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
public void getInit() {
    video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    media_Controller = new MediaController(this);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_READ_STORAGE);
    Hash_file_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/VIDEOS/");
    File[] listFile = file.listFiles();
    for (File f : listFile) {
        String name = f.getName();
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (name.endsWith(".mp4")) {
   video_player_view.setVideoPath(Hash_file_maps.put(listFile[i].getName(), listFile[i].getAbsolutePath()));

            }
        }
    }
video_player_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            video_player_view.start();

        }
    });
}
```

I could not able to realize where i did mistake,Could you please help me.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775722/can-i-loop-multiple-videos-stored-on-raw-folder-in-videoview

Answer (score 2):

once try

```
  //Video Loop
    video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            video_view.start(); //need to make transition seamless.
        }
    });


    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample_2);
    video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
    video_view.start();
```

Comment: its lopping one video only

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be setting the video source to a value, and then immediately to another value and so on in a loop, without actually playing the video.

It looks like you are maybe expecting 'setVideoPath' to add all the videos to a list to be played, but the documentation is clear it is setting just a single path:

> setVideoPath
>
> void setVideoPath (String path)
>
> Sets video path.

The link @sasikumar provided in the comments is a good example to look at.